# How to put Preference into a View?

Tags: android, preferences, android-preferences

I need to make a Screen with Header(Will contain ImageView and TextView) and Footer(Navigation Menu, will consists of ImageView), in the between I need to have Preference screen with all the default action like scrolling and setting preferences.

Which approach should I take to achieve this?

Right now, I have made a View with FrameLayout in the middle where I can put the View I want in it. But how can I put a PreferenceActivity in it?

Answer (score 1):

PreferenceActivity is automated way to get generic preference screen. If you need extra UI elements, you have to implement it manually. It will take more time, but isn't too hard and you can design it any way you want.

Comment: A link:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceActivity.html